# Multiline variable in Ansible playbook without newlines (spaces)

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to define a "complex" (with quotes) multiline variable in Ansible. I don't want spaces as a result of the multiline setup. A "newline" at the end of each line is translated into a space. I have tried escaping the newline with "" as indicated in many questions/answers on the internet, but Ansible seems to ignore the "".

Code example:

```
      set_fact: 
        test: >-
          "v=DKIM1; k=rsa;" "p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkwetuwweeTYRjEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCA\
          QEAtJltC/t70wayxq0Rws5R7t+Q2GZ2llnY0nSHDkVnP9kDaYBTyHCk+OoiCehHjUr\
          9/60Rp7v5xDiS9ta5w8c4pyqgWCIvj7iCPVfVzEtSfOp0iwmvGvKeBMhY62+7BYyQ5\
          zOt45pJHVqQt78/L2S75AZY2RUVv85AXXUlx8Os54dBz8DsdnWilH+o0Ce+ZAor70i\
          z0TkEVCnuom" "3xv/bLbOyFI7EoxbhU2NVIer3uanPbl6HUr4B2P3y695yh4fi+oq\
          oOAM8Ah0rx0iruqcgoEPhNriEJ1PxW6ZDwFFnDgmR3hCaULQl4OtkWGwhG87ISBxC3\
          66xBjT+rTLys1yT0uu3QIDAQAB""
```

This leads to spaces everywhere there is a newline (at the end of the lines). E.g.:

```
"v=DKIM1; k=rsa;" "p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkwetuwweeTYRjEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCA (space!!!) QEAtJltC/t70wayxq0Rws5R7t+Q2GZ2llnY0nSHDkVnP9kDaYBTyHCk+OoiCehHjUr...
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [folded style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#813-folded-style) and split the lines. Then join them. For example, given the simplified data

```yaml
    test: |-
       "v=DKIM1; k=rsa;" "p=MIIB
       QEAtJltC/t70wayxq0Rws5R7"
```

The debug task

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ test|split('\n')|join }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: '"v=DKIM1; k=rsa;" "p=MIIBQEAtJltC/t70wayxq0Rws5R7"'
```

---

For Ansible less than 2.11 use *split* as a method

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ test.split('\n')|join }}"
```

Comment: Seems like a working solution, however I get the following error: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: no filter named 'split'. String: {{ test | split('\n') | join }}"}. Any ideas how to get the split filer installed?

Comment: ``split`` is available as a function since 2.11. Either upgrade or use it as a method ``{{ test.split('\n')|join }}``.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```yaml
set_fact:
  test: 'a\
    b\
    c'
```

If you use a variable, you can use:

```
set_fact:
  my_var: abc

set_fact:
  test: >-
    {{ my_var -}}
    def
    {{- my_var }}
```

That will result in 'abcdefabc'.